# Generally and conceptually, what do these sections mean on vSphere?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, virtual-machine, storage, vsphere

I am a complete newbie in virtual machines.

I have vSphere and am at the "Summary" page of one VM. Under the "Capacity and Usage" section, I see CPU, Memory, and Storage. Then under the "VM Hardware" section, I see "Hard disk 1: ### GB|Thin Provision".

My question is, where do things on the VM get stored - in CPU, Memory, Storage, or Hard disk? For example, if I wanted to store billions of log messages from the VM, which of the 4 would I allocate more resources to?

I'm very new to computer science, so please use simple terms. Thanks :)

Comment: You need to get the VMware Documentation and various Tutorials to help you learn.

Comment: `"Hard disk 1: ### GB|Thin Provision"` is a type of Storage. We know files are stored on disk, rather than in memory (as it's volatile) and the CPU is for calculations, not storage. If you're not familiar with these concepts, you're trying to run an ultra-marathon before you can walk.